# Nulls in Data frame . How to remove if it is better in Logistic regresion models

Tags: r, null

I have a Data Frame with two columns that have populations of NULL in them

```
  'data.frame': 31337 obs. of  16 variables:
  # $ ID                       : int  1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
  # $ Target                   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  # $ band                     : chr  "3. 35 to 44" "NULL" "NULL" "NULL" ...
  # $ gender                   : chr  "Male" "NULL" "Male" "NULL" ...
```

a) Do I remove the Rows with "Null" in R or 
b) do I leave the Null as a seperate category for Logistic Regression in R ?

If the answer to a is yes then how do I do it

Comment: You should first try to find out what `NULL` supposed to mean in your data. See for example `$ gender  : chr  "Male" "NULL" "Male" "NULL"`. A bit difficult make sense what that means.

Comment: In my opinion you will get more appropriate answer of your question in  https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

There are several things going on here with your question.

- "NULL" in your data frame is a character value. It is not `NULL`.

E.g.,

```
is.null(NULL)
[1] TRUE
is.null("NULL")
[1] FALSE
```

- In R there is a difference between `NULL` and `NA`. `NULL` represents a null or empty object. It is often returned by functions so that values are undefined. `NA` is a missing value (does not exist). Based on your context, I would replace your "NULL" values with `NA`. For a quick way to replace "NULL" with `NA`, see `dplyr::na_if()`. ([Link](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/na_if.html) to function's documentation.)
- If you are using `glm()` to carry out your logistic regression model there are several ways `glm()` handles missing data (NAs). You can control how it handles NAs with the argument `na.action`. Run `?glm` in the console to pull up the help page for this function. There is a description of each of the argument's values.

To answer your question about removing NAs or using a dummy indicator for missing values, that's a matter of model intent. It is difficult to provide a general answer to such a broad topic without more details.

Answer (score 0):

@jordan .. Fantastic advice .. dataframe shrunk to 14% of size

data=na_if(data,"NULL")
data <- data[!is.na(data$age_band) & !is.na(data$gender), ]

Comment: if my answer addressed your question, feel free to check my answer to accept it.